# Как брать из .txt файла 10 строк для 10 строк в БД?

Tags: python, telethon

У меня есть файл .txt с прокси, мне надо чтобы для 10 аккаунтов телеграмма брался 1 прокси и т.д, помогите, пожалуйста.

Код записи прокси в БД:

```
def get_proxy(proxy_str: str):
    ptype = getattr(socks, config.proxy_type.upper())
    credentials, address = proxy_str.split('@')
    login, password = credentials.split(':')
    ip, port = address.split(':')
    port = int(port)
    return ptype, ip, port, True, login, password


def get_new_proxy():
    with DB() as db:
        db_proxies = db.get_proxies()
    with open(config.proxy_file, encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file_proxies = file.read().split("\n")
    for proxy in file_proxies:
        if proxy not in db_proxies or db_proxies.count(proxy) < config.max_accs_per_proxy:
            return proxy
    return None
```

Конфиг:

```
group_links = ["XXXX"]
forward_to = ["XXXX"]
proxy_type = "socks5"
max_accs_per_proxy = 10
proxy_required = True # True/False

json_required = False
default_json = {
    "phone": "",
    "app_id": XXXXX,
    "app_hash": "XXXX",
    "sdk": "Windows 10",
    "device": "PC 64bit",
    "app_version": "4.8.10 x64",
    "lang_pack": "en",
    "system_lang_pack": "en-us"
}

proxy_file = "../malling_bot_payment/proxy.txt"
autoresponder_file = "autoresponder.txt"
comment_file = "text.txt"

database_path = "accounts.db"
accounts_path = r"F:\pythonProject\malling_bot_payment\accounts"
logs_path = "logs.log"

random_string_len = 0
small_delay = (5, 15)

delete_account_if_dead = True
```

загрузка акков в БД с прокси:

```
with DB() as db:
    db.create_tables()

for account in accounts_files:
    phone = Path(account).stem
    with DB() as db:
        db.insert_account(phone)
        _, proxy, sent_time, joined, text_file, autoresponder_text = db.get_account(phone)
        joined = "" if not joined else joined

    if not proxy:
        proxy = get_new_proxy()
        if not proxy and proxy_required:
            logger.warning(f"аккаунт {phone} не загружен. Причина: нет свободных прокси")
            continue
        with DB() as db:
            db.update_proxy(phone, proxy)
    if proxy:
        proxy = get_proxy(proxy)

    if os.path.exists(f"{accounts_path}\\{phone}.json"):
        with open(f"{accounts_path}\\{phone}.json", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            json_data = load(file)
    elif not json_required:
        json_data = {
            "session_file": phone,
              "phone": phone,
               "app_id": 21682771,
               "app_hash": "e271a7a8b85a4f96bf45d93a391cf2f2",
               "sdk": "Windows 10",
               "device": "PC 64bit",
               "app_version": "4.8.10 x64",
               "lang_pack": "en",
               "system_lang_pack": "en-us"}
    else:
        logger.error(f"аккаунт {phone} не загружен. Причина: нет json аккаунта")
        continue
    client = TelegramClient(
        session=account,
        api_id=json_data["app_id"],
        api_hash=json_data["app_hash"],
        device_model=json_data["device"],
        system_version=json_data["sdk"],
        app_version=json_data["app_version"],
        lang_code=json_data["lang_pack"],
        system_lang_code=json_data["system_lang_pack"],
        proxy=proxy
    )
    client.parse_mode = "html"
    accounts.append(
        {
            "client": client,
            "sent_time": sent_time,
            "joined": joined,
            "phone": phone,
        }
    )
    logger.info(f"аккаунт {phone} загружен")
```

Структура БД:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл proxy.txt:
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX
TG:proxysoxybot@XXXX

Тут 20 прокси, они должны использоваться для 10 акков, а в моём коде они используются для 20 акков, то есть 1 прокси = 1 акк, а надо 1 прокси = 10 акков